# onclick check box not work

Tags: javascript

I made a script that  `onClick` shows/ hides a dropdown list here is the code.

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="user_choice" id="user_choice" onclick="checktoggle();"/>
 <label for="user_choice">Show Map</label>
 </br>
 <select name="radius_out_map" id="radius_out_map" style="display:none">
     <option value="0">-- Select Distance Radius --</option>
     <option value="10">10 Km.</option>
     <option value="20">20 Km.</option>
     <option value="50">50 Km.</option>
     <option value="100">100 Km.</option>
     <option value="300">300 Km.</option>
     <option value="500">500 Km.</option>
 </select>
```

**JAVASCTIPT :**

```
<script language="javascript">
    function checktoggle() {
        var textboxid = document.getElementById('radius_out_map');
     if (textboxid.style.display == 'none') {
         textboxid.style.display = 'show';
     }
     else {
         textboxid.style.display = 'none';
     }
}
</script>
```

Why does this script not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
textboxid.style.display = 'show'
```

Use this:

```
textboxid.style.display = 'block'
```

show is not a valid option for display, either use inline or block to show the element.

Check the list of valid values [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 2):

'show' is not valid. You will need to use 'inline' or 'block'

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
textboxid.style.display = 'show'
```

to

```
textboxid.style.display = 'block'
```

show is not valid.